# Retrieve unique values from 'with' Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm currently using Laravel 9. I need help refactoring a query that I have created. I eager load a relationship `users` here:

`$items = Item::where('type', 'user')->with('users')->get();`

Which brings me back a collection of Items with the associated Users. What I would love is a unique list of all of the associated Users, but I'm struggling to figure out how I do it through a query, or maybe a function map.

This is what I have tried to get the list I want, but it feels like a lot of code, and I imagine there is a much better way of doing this.

```
$items = Item::where('type', 'user')->with('users')->get();
$users = new Collection();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $itemUsers = $item->users()->get();
    $users = $users->merge($itemUsers);
}

$uniqueUsers = $users->unique();
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could improve this please, without iterating over the `$items` in a foreach?

Comment: what do you mean by `unique list` ?

Comment: @xenooooo When you query a Model for a list of associated Records, then combine each `Item`'s `User` records, you will likely end up with duplicates, especially if it's a `many-to-many`.

Comment: @xenooooo a unique collection or array would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying from the `Item` model, start your query from the `User` model, and constrain them to only those that have an associated `Item` with `type` of `user`:

```
$users = User::whereHas('items', function ($subQuery) {
  return $subQuery->where('items.type', 'user');
})->get();
```

This requires having the inverse of the relationship defined on your `User` model. You currently have `public function users()` in your `Item` model, you should also have `public function item()` (or `public function items()`) in your `User` mode. Adjust the code as required (i.e. `whereHas('items')` or `whereHas('item')`).

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense to go about it via the inverse.